# How to use a range-based for loop with a vector of future<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std-future

I have a program that calculates some values in different threads with `std::packaged_task<int()>`. I store the `std::future` I get from the packaged tasks via `get_future()` in a vector (defined as `std::vector<std::future<int>>`).

When I calculate the sum of all the tasks I use a for loop and it's working:

```cpp
// set up of the tasks
std::vector<std::future<int>> results;
// store the futures in results
// each task execute in its own thread

int sum{ 0 };
for (auto i = 0; i < results.size; ++i) {
    sum += results[i].get();
}
```

But I would rather use a range-based for loop:

```cpp
// set up of the tasks
std::vector<std::future<int>> results;
// store the futures in results
// each task execute in its own thread

int sum{ 0 };
for (const auto& result : results) {
    sum += result.get();
}
```

Currently I get a compile error with clang:

```
program.cxx:83:16: error: 'this' argument to member function 'get' has type 'const std::function<int>', but function is not marked const

       sum += result.get();
              ^~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.1.0/../../../../include/c++/9.1.0/future:793:7: note: 'get' declared here

       get()
       ^
```

Is it possible to use [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with a `vector` of `future<int>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `const` from `for (const auto& result : results)`.  `std::future` does not provide a const qualified version of `get` which is what the compiler is trying to call since `result` is a reference to a `const std::future`.

```
for (auto& result : results) {
    sum += result.get();
}
```

Does what you want.

Answer (score 4):

`get`is not `const`, so you need non-const references:

```
for (auto& result : results) {
    sum += result.get();
}
```